# List of unlocked artifact rewards

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth, civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide

I'm trying to see the artifact rewards that I have already unlocked. I checked all info screens such as artifacts, research and even notifications, but I cannot find it. Am I blind or is this currently missing?

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/65980/discussions/0/487870763303515386/), it doesn't look like this is currently a feature (though it seems like it would be greatly appreciated)

> I don't think there is any such list of unlocks-you-have-already-gotten from combining artifacts.

I realize this probably isn't what you are looking for, since it is not in-game, but [here](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Artifacts_(Rising_Tide)#Artifact_rewards) is a list of all artifact rewards.